# Unicode fun #1832672: This comment can't be voted on seem to have an interesting close icon

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-votes

While reading an old locked answer, I tried to upvote a comment, not thinking about the lock, and was presented with this dialog:

[image: Dialog saying that a message is not voteable with a problematic icon]

I don't really want to hunt out comments to flag on locked post, am I the only one who sees this?

---

I'm on windows 10, with Chrome 71.0.3578.98, the only plugin that seems activated is uBlock Origins.

Comment: Happy christmas freehand circle...

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing after flagging a post for closure on meta.se. win10, chrome, etc

Comment: The old X wasn't working, so SO decided to emphasize it with UTF-8. Either that, or they switched to PHP when we weren't looking

Comment: This also appears when clicking on recent badges in a profile, e.g. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IshC1.png).

Comment: Just got the same when close voting a post

Comment: Retracting a close vote also shows the problem, but in **blue**.

Comment: @Machavity Stack Exchange is [migrating to **.NET Core**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323148/263422) this week.

Comment: This problem seems to be consistent across all dialog boxes. I've tested it fairly thoroughly, and all of them had the same results.

Comment: A similar problem i've reported was fixed already: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379636/5675325 .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct symbol here is the Unicode "multiplication sign", or "×" character.

Apparently some editors don't handle this well and replace it with a string of mojibake. As per usual, Unicode ruins everything.

The correct symbol has been restored.

Comment: *...some editors...* are you blaming tools or people here?

Comment: @rene:  *Mojibake* is 99.99% of the time [caused by tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), so I would presume that's what's happened here.  I'm only getting wicked flashbacks from when I had to deal with encoding issues...