# Odd looking “Close” button on messages after close voting

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

[image: Error in question]

Likely the [same reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379617/unicode-fun-1832672-this-comment-cant-be-voted-on-seem-to-have-an-interesting) as [this other bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379621/odd-looking-close-button-on-error-message) but I'm used to reporting cases like these, to have a record of all the places a bug occurs.

This can be closed as a dupe.

Comment: Well...I just realised I can close my own question as a dupe.

Comment: Oh look here's this question ÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁÁgain